# How to Open a file in the kernel using only the inode

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

I am currently trying to open, read, write to a specific file in the (Linux) kernel space.

I know that `filp_open`, `kernel_write` functions could be used to perform the same effects as open, write in the user space. But these functions require a `pathname`.

Considering that I only know the location(on the disk) of the `inode`, is there anyway to open a file?

By opening a file, I mean is there a way to create the `struct file` and the `(in-memory)struct` inode from only the (on-disk) Inode?

I understood that there might be permission problems, but since it's the kernel accessing the files, this problem might go away?

Thank you for your time!